# I'm trying to check if an abbreviation is not part of a word

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I'm trying to check if an abbreviation which is stored in column abbr exist in the name of the company of the same entity(same row) but not the ones that the abbreviation is part of the a word.

Here is an example:

| name | abbr |
| --- | --- |
| ALCON | co |
| MIDTOWN BEEF CO | co |
| SOUTH SHORE CO ACTION COUNCIL | co |

and my code is:

```
display(df.filter(col('name').contains(col('abbr'))))
```

I want to get only `MIDTOWN BEEF CO` and `SOUTH SHORE CO ACTION COUNCIL` but my code returns all of them

Comment: I would split the string into a Array, with a delimiter of a space. Then you can check for exact matches or if the string begins with the letters, depending on the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to check if the `name` contains the word token `abbr` as a standalone word, not just a string-contains.

There are two ways to do this:

1. Split the `name` on spaces and use the `array_contains()` spark SQL function:

```py
>>> df.filter(array_contains(split(df.name, ' '), df.abbr)).show()
+--------------------+----+
|                name|abbr|
+--------------------+----+
|     MIDTOWN BEEF CO|  CO|
|SOUTH SHORE CO AC...|  CO|
+--------------------+----+
```

2. Or use regex with a **word boundary** `\b` matcher:

```py
>>> df.filter("name regexp concat('\\\\b', abbr, '\\\\b')").show()
+--------------------+----+
|                name|abbr|
+--------------------+----+
|     MIDTOWN BEEF CO|  CO|
|SOUTH SHORE CO AC...|  CO|
+--------------------+----+
```

Option #2 is better if your names have punctuation in them too such as `MIDTOWN BEEF CO.` (this will not work with Option #1 but it will with #2).

Comment: Thank you @Zach. It worked. I was looking for a short and elegant solution which you provided.